# Delete children in Grails

Tags: hibernate, jpa, grails, grails-orm

I have two entities in Grails

```
class SO {
}
```

and

```
class ProDContr {
    SO serviceOrder
}
```

when I tried to delete an entity SO I need to delete ProdContr too, but I have this error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sa`.`prod_contr`, CONSTRAINT `FK_tr7jdqc75qy0tkxnysv35ele3` FOREIGN KEY (`so_id`) REFERENCES `so` (`id`)).
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell GORM about the relationship between a `ProDContr` and an `SO`.

In this case it looks like you need a `belongsTo` in your `ProDContr` domain:

```
class ProDContr {
    static belongsTo = [serviceOrder: SO]
}
```

This will cascade deletes from `SO` down to the related `ProDContr`s.

You can read more about this behavior in the [GORM docs on cascading updates and deletes](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#cascades).

Comment: @MisterB Please consider accepting this answer if it is the solution to your problem